# gulp-filter filters out all files

Tags: javascript, filter, build-process, gulp, gulp-filter

I'm working on moving my workflow over to Gulp, and I'm loving it so far; however, I seem to have misunderstood something about how the gulp-filter plugin works...

I have the following task:

```
gulp.task('assets', function() {
    var stylesFilter = gulpFilter(stylesPath);
    var imagesFilter = gulpFilter(imagesPath);
    var scriptsFilter = gulpFilter(scriptsPath);

    return gulp.src([].concat('app/**/*.html', stylesPath, imagesPath, scriptsPath))
        // STYLES
        .pipe(stylesFilter)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/test_styles')) // For debugging!
        .pipe(sass({style: 'expanded' }))
        .pipe(autoPrefixer('> 1%', 'last 3 versions', 'Firefox ESR', 'Opera 12.1'))
        .pipe(concat('main.css'))
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(revReplace())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
        .pipe(stylesFilter.restore())

        // SCRIPTS
        .pipe(scriptsFilter)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/test_scripts')) // For debugging!
        .pipe(jsHint('.jshintrc'))
        .pipe(jsHint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(revReplace())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
        .pipe(scriptsFilter.restore())

        // IMAGES
        .pipe(imagesFilter)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/test_images')) // For debugging!
        .pipe(cache(imageMin({ optimizationLevel: 7, progressive: true, interlaced: true })))
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(revReplace())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'))
        .pipe(imagesFilter.restore());
});
```

The path variables I'm using are defined as follows:

```
var stylesPath = [
    'bower_components/foundation/scss/normalize.scss', 
    'bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation.scss',
    'app/styles/app.scss'
],
scriptsPath = [
    'app/scripts/**/*.js',
    '!app/scripts/**/*_test.js'
],
imagesPath = [
    'app/images/**/*'
];
```

My problem is that the `stylesFilter`, `imagesFilter`, and `scriptsFilter` are filtering out *everything*! I've tried adding the lines marked as "for debugging" in the task above in order to see which files it is working on in each filtered section, which shows that *all* files are being filtered out (i.e. no files are written to disk with the gulp.dest() statements marked as being for debugging above). If I add a line for outputting the files after any of the `.pipe(*Filter.restore())` lines it outputs all the files from the original input (which are the correct files). I've also, for good measure, tried using a negated pattern for the filters, but that had the exact same result.

So what am I missing? Why is *nothing* returned by the filters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, so I've found the reason for this behavior:

`gulp-filter` uses the multimatch module behind the scenes, and it uses Vinyl file objects for the files it reads, and it passes `File.relative` to the multimatch function (which is the relative path in relation to `File.base`, which is equal to the first glob). So when I used `'bower_components/foundation/scss/normalize.scss'` as a glob `File.relative` only contained the file name, and `'bower_components/foundation/scss/normalize.scss'` doesn't match `'normalize.scss'`.

Answer (score 1):

Your pipeline is way too long and attempt to process unrelated things.

I'd rather start a pipeline per type of asset in different tasks running in parallel.

Comment: Normally I'd agree with you; but actually, I don't think I can separate this into 3 tasks since I want to use the `gulp-rev` and `gulp-rev-replace` plugins. It needs to read the .html files and update the references to the asset files with the versioned names, and if the 3 tasks run in parallel there is no way (or rather, no non-insanely ugly way) to make sure each .html file is read, updated, and written before another task tries to do the same (task1 could read it, then task2, then task1 could write its changes, then task2 could write its changes, overwriting what task1 did).