# gulp-filter is filtering everything

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-filter

gulp-filter is filtering everything.

I'm trying to use [gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter) to exclude a single file from [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify/):

```js
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var filter = require('gulp-filter');

var paths = {
    css: 'src/*.css',
    html: 'src/*.html',
    js: 'src/*.js'
};

gulp.task('js', function() {
    // Create a filter for the ToC options file. We don't want to minify that.
    var f = filter(['*', '!src/ToCOptions.js'], {"restore": true});

    return gulp.src(paths.js)
        .pipe(f)
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(f.restore)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
});
```

I've read [gulp-filter filters out all files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24687468/2948042), which seems to be the same problem, but the accepted answer doesn't work for me.

I've tried several variations on the filter, including:

- `var f = filter(['*', '!ToCOptions.js'], {"restore": true});`
  Nothing processed by gulp-uglify.
- `var f = filter('!ToCOptions.js', {"restore": true});`
  Nothing processed by gulp-uglify.
- `var f = filter('!src/ToCOptions.js', {"restore": true});`
  Nothing processed by gulp-uglify.
- `var f = filter('src/ToCOptions.js', {"restore": true});`
  Only the file I wanted to exclude was processed by gulp-uglify.
- `var f = filter(['*', 'src/ToCOptions.js'], {"restore": true});`
  Only the file I wanted to exclude was processed by gulp-uglify.
- `var f = filter(['*', '!/src/ToCOptions.js'], {"restore": true});`
  Nothing processed by gulp-uglify.
- `var f = filter(['*', '!/ToCOptions.js'], {"restore": true});`
  Nothing processed by gulp-uglify.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think `on("data", (file)=>{})` event will help you

Comment: @The can you provide a little more information or, even better, a link to a an example with an explanation? It looks like an event handler. What type of value is the argument passed to it... string?... object? I probably should have mentioned that I'm fairly new to Gulp and I've never worked with Node.js outside of Gulp.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, this is an error in the documentation that is explained in [issue #55](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-filter/issues/55) at the Github repository.

The solution in my case is this:

```js
var f = filter(['**', '!src/ToCOptions.js'], {'restore': true});
```

As the author of the issue explains, a single asterisk only matches files that are not in subdirectories. All of the files for this task are in a subdirectory, so the first pattern didn't match anything and the second pattern didn't have any results to [*subtract from*](https://github.com/sindresorhus/multimatch#how-multiple-patterns-work).

To understand `**`, I had to use `man bash` on a Linux system and search for *globstar* since the [node-glob documentation](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) makes reference to the Bash implementation:

```
globstar
    If  set,  the  pattern  ** used in a pathname expansion context will
    match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If the
    pattern is followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories match.
```

Comment: Woah! You saved my day :)

Comment: thx Vince, helped me much. Btw., this is how I filtered out all *.min.js files: var f = filter(['**', '!**/*.min.js'], {'restore': true});

Answer (score 2):

I've create a simple example with `on("data", function(file){})` just to make your understanding more clear around *NodeJS Streams*.

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src("my/js/folder/*.js")
    .on("data", function(file){
       console.log(file)
       // here you can filter all your file depends on name/path/etc. 
    })
    ... 
    do something else
    ...
    the same you can do in gulp.dest method
    .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file){
       // conditions
       ...
       return "my expected path"/* your expected path for file depends on conditions*/
    }))
});
```

I hope it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: It didn't help in this case. The pattern I was using didn't match anything at all, so there wasn't any data when I put it in the stream after the filter. However, I think knowing about `.on('data', function(file){})` is going to come in very handy in the future. Thank you.

Comment: @Vince dont use pattern and `gulp-filter`. For `gulp.src` use simple folders like '["src/js/*.js", "src/css/*.css"]' and filter it inside `on("data")`

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I didn't get any farther than `console.log` because I don't know what to do with `file`. I could probably start to understand if I read the [Vinyl documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs), but this is like reinventing the wheel. Learning how to filter files from `gulp.src` without using a plugin would be valuable in the long run, but in this case I just need to know how to use the plugin correctly.